# Symantec Flagging my powershell script as virus

Tags: windows, powershell, anti-virus

Was wondering if anyone could shed light about why symantec is think my script is a virus.
i have a powershell script which is then compiled to exe file. our domain users run this script
what it does - it goes to a shared path, it shows the user list of all the executables in the shared path, then the user check which exec files he wants to run. then the script write on another shared path the pc name %hostname% to a txt file(if there is a file like that it deletes it).
here it is:(i deleted the GUI parts from it as it isnt necessary for the discussion

```
$BucketPath = '\\srv\x$\xx'
$BucketDBPath = '\\srv\x$\xxB$'
$PdfPath = '\\srv\s$\xxxx$\pdf$'

Function Install(){
    if (Test-Path $xx\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt ) { Remove-Item $xxx\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt }
        ForEach ($item in $listBox1.SelectedItems) {
            if (Test-Path $PdfPath\$item.pdf){Start-Process ((Resolve-Path "$xx\$item.pdf").path)}
           # "$item.exe" | Out-File $xxx\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt 
            echo "$item.exe" >> $xx\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt 
               }
              $form.close()}
.
.
.

[void]$form.ShowDialog()}
$data = gci $BucketPath | %{$_.BaseName}
$programlist = $data
```

Comment: I assume this is new behavior, it will be impossible for us to determine the reason a specific antivirus engine is has generated a false positive on your executable.  The engine used by your antivirus isn’t open source.  Report the false positive to Symantec, create an specific exclusion for the executable, as it will be impossible for us to determine the real reason for the false positive

Comment: Powershell is the most popular language on malware authors. I would upload the script to virustotal.com and see what the other scanners report. Additionally this should be an easy way to get the script white-listed as the different anti-virus scanner companies get all the uploaded samples.

Comment: Put this script and any associated executables in the central whitelist using the Symantec Management Console on the Server. That normally works very well.

Comment: Script-packagers such as UPX are listed by just about every antivirus engine, because they are often used by script kiddies and amateur exploit writers to convey malicious payloads, and in a decent professional systems admin situation they are not needed.

Comment: Thank you verymuch all of you, I appriciate your time!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you need to cert sign the app.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing?view=powershell-7

Comment: I dont think this got anything to do with the virus signature its something else though i appriciate your answer, thank you!